# How to reset Cypress window.location.href after test

Tags: javascript, cypress, integration-testing

I am testing some ui that on click updates the `window.location.href`. I have two tests, the first one works, but the second starts in the location set by the ui in the previous test. This is wrong and stops test two from starting on the right page.

How can I reset the `window.location.href` or just the Cypress browser location in general back to where it was at the beginning of the first test?

I have checked the window.location.href at the start of the second test and it looks autogenerated and so I don't think wise to try and hardcode that value into window.location.href at the start of the second test.

Looking for something I can run at `afterEach`.

Test

```
it.only('should send asynchronous analytics event after provider selection click', () => {
    rewire$useFlag(() => true);
    cy.location().then((location) => console.log('window !!'));
    const analyticsAsyncStub = cy.stub().as('sendAnalyticsAsyncStub');
    rewire$sendAnalyticsAsync(analyticsAsyncStub);

    // @NOTE hacking browser detection so required provider options are availiable
    cy.window().then(($window) => {
        console.log('window !!', $window.location.href);
        ($window as any).chrome = {};
        ($window as any).chrome.runtime = {
            sendMessage() {
                'mock function';
            },
        };
    });

    mountFixtureWithProviders({ children: <ProviderSelection flagsConfig={defaultFlags} /> });
    cyGetByTestId('provider--metaMask').click();

    cy.get('@sendAnalyticsAsyncStub').should(
        'have.been.calledWithMatch',
        analyticsUtilsModule.createButtonEvent(ButtonEventName.providerSelectionPressed),
    );
});
```

mountFixtureWithProviders function

```
export const mountFixtureWithProviders = ({
children,
mountInsideVisualMock = true,
setErrorLog = () => ({}),
renderErrorScreens,
}: {
    children: ReactNode;
    mountInsideVisualMock?: boolean;
    setErrorLog?: SetErrorLog;
    renderErrorScreens?: boolean;
}) => {
    const RouterMockedChildren = () => <MemoryRouter>{children}. 
</MemoryRouter>;
    const ProvidedChildren = () =>
        renderErrorScreens ? (
            <DemoAppToRenderErrorMessages>
                <RouterMockedChildren />
            </DemoAppToRenderErrorMessages>
        ) : (
            <LinkUiCoreContext.Provider value={{ setErrorLog, 
imageResizerServiceUrl: DEV_IMAGE_RESIZER_SERVICE_URL }}>
                <RouterMockedChildren />
            </LinkUiCoreContext.Provider>
        );
    return mount(mountInsideVisualMock ? linkPageVisualMock({ 
children: <ProvidedChildren /> }) : <ProvidedChildren />);
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can just do a visit in a `beforeEach()` to get a clean start for each test

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('/')
})
```

There's also `cy.go('back')` which you can run at the end of the first test.

But be aware that a fail in test 1 will then fail test 2 because the navigation won't happen - same applies to adding into `afterEach()`.

---

In Cypress `window` is the test runner window, but you can access the app window with

```js
cy.window().then(win => console.log(win.location.href))
```

or the location directly with

```js
cy.location().then(loc => console.log(loc.href))
```

Don't use `cy.log()` for debugging, use `console.log()` as there are side-effects to `cy.log()` that may give you the wrong debugging info.

---

`(mountFixtureWithProviders({ children: <ProviderSelection flagsConfig={{}} /> })` looks like a component test, so yes I agree that should give you a fresh start for each test.

Can you add the two tests and also `mountFixtureWithProviders` in the question to give the full picture please.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm finding that `visits` and `go(back)` aren't working because the starting location(in test 1) isn't `/` and the starting location isn't simple (looks auto generated). Perhaps you know of a way to essentially start the next test in some sort of fresh instance so to speak?

Comment: Could you show how you do the initial visit? That would be what you need to use in the `beforeEach()`.

Comment: You could do some complicated stuff with `cy.location().href` but it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Also might be useful to see the "generated" URL, maybe a clue there.

Comment: Generated URL `http://localhost:57592/__cypress/iframes//Users/danielblythe/code/company_name/icvmx-link/src/components/ProviderSelection/ProviderSelection.test.cy.tsx`.  Initial visit is done like this `(mountFixtureWithProviders({ children: <ProviderSelection flagsConfig={{}} /> });`. I use `mountFixtureWithProviders` in each `it` so would have thought that would mount a fresh comp which would be set at the same place test 1 starts.

Comment: I get the generated URL by running `cy.log(window.location.href)` in the test.

Comment: Try `cy.window().then(win => console.log(win.location.href))`. In Cypress `window` is the test runner window, but you can access the app window with `cy.window().then(win =>...` or the location directly with `cy.location().then(loc =>...`.

Comment: thank you. `cy.location` and `cy.window` don't appear to be logging anything in Cypress. Although I can open dev tools in Cypress and see a `Yielded` log which includes lots of location info but it all looks like the same generated URL and so I might actually just be looking at the test runner window again. SO is suggesting we move to a chat?

Comment: Yes, my mistake in component tests there is no separate window for the app. (Unlike e2e tests which has a window object specifically for the app).

Comment: Let's start over, you can add the tests to the question to give some clarity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245277/discussion-between-daniel-blythe-and-fody).

Comment: Hope it's ok that I've moved to a chat room. I've also added the code from my first test.